# Are articles needed in "sift signal from noise"? Is it the right word order?

Tags: articles, definite-article, word-order

I have 2 related questions.

1. What is the correct expression in English? Is it with "the" or without it? In my research I have found roughly the same instances of both. If both are ok and there is a difference, could you explain it?

   - sift signal from noise
   - sift the signal from the noise
2. Does signal always go before noise? Why? In my research of examples that almost always seemed to be the case. Or can I invert the order as follows?

   - sift noise from signal
   - sift the noise from the signal

PS: I am referring to the figurative expression (and not to its literal usage in electrical engineering).

Comment: Whether we use **the** or not simply depends on whether we're talking about signal or noise as general concepts, or specific instances.

Answer (score 0):

I initially thought that it *ought* to include 'the' in all cases, but in speech or scientific chat they could easily be dropped. However, I noticed as I'm typing this that I almost never actually want to use 'the' - perhaps as I'm not being specific as to which 'items' I am referring to.
If I said, "Once you have your audio sample, you then sift the signal from the noise." I'm now referring to one specific instance which needs sifting, and 'the' becomes far more appropriate.

You could argue that the order of *sift x from y* really depends on which you want to keep, but that's easily shown to not be true.

You sift lumps from flour - you discard what is left in the sieve, and keep that which falls through. As far as I'm aware this is the origin of the term, though ordinarily the lumps are not even significant to the process; you just sift the flour.

You sift signal from noise - but now you're keeping what's left over in your 'sieve' and discarding that which falls through.
One could perhaps argue that it ought to be 'sift noise from signal', so you discard the noise & let the signal fall through the sieve.

I think in this particular instance it may just be convention. We only ever talk about *signal to noise ratio* [SNR] & never *noise to signal ratio*, so maybe we are 'following form' in that we expect to hear the term signal first.

Comment: Don't we sometimes do the opposite i.e. we discard what falls through and keep what's left over in the sieve? (e.g. pasta after boiling or when washing lentils)

Comment: Please note that I have edited my question to specify that I am referring to the figurative expression (and not to its literal usage in electrical engineering). Not sure if it changes your answer.

Comment: As a figurative expression then it's down to whether you're referring to a specific super-set of signal & noise or generic; as in my opening paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

> I am referring to the figurative expression (and not to its literal usage in electrical engineering).

Thanks for the context - it helps.

I would use "the" with both nouns as I also assume that the context includes an earlier reference to "what people are saying". i.e. the signal, and "the various imperfect ways they are saying it", i.e. the noise.

> Does signal always go before noise?

Usually, (usually does not mean "always") the thing you want is the first item, unless the following sentence or clause refers to the unwanted item.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen many examples of writers using "the" even though there is no previous reference or specificity. I wonder why that happens...?

Comment: @lorentz "the" can be used with a word or phrase that is familiar to the listener "The moon is bright" is correct because everyone knows what you are talking about. When people use "to the sift signal from the noise", then they assume that this phrase is well known to the audience. It is more likely to be used in the literal sense.

Answer (score 0):

It could depend on context - are you speaking about the *ability* to separate these two things, or a specific instance of doing so?

'Signal' is a countable noun, so it needs an article if it is not plural. Although 'noise' can be non-countable, it should have a definite article in your example because it is *specific* noise that is being separated from the signal. You couldn't isolate and separate something from an abstract concept.

If you were talking about separating these two things *in general*, you should say:

> You can separate *signals* from *noise*.

'Signals' is always countable, so it is a plural; noise can remain abstract because it is only possible that there may be noise.

If you are talking about a specific instance of this action, you should say:

> You can separate *the signal* from *the noise*.

The definite article is appropriate as they are looking for a *specific* signal. If we are talking about radio signals, there are lots of signals everywhere, transmitted from all different places and on different frequencies. To receive or hear one, we have to isolate it, so you can see why they are countable.

I don't accept suggestions in other answers and comments that 'signal' can be non-countable, at least not in English grammar. Perhaps it is used that way as *technical jargon* in the field of radio communication, but if so, the majority of English speakers that do not work in that field may not recognise it. Many fields have their own terminology and it does not necessarily follow the rules of grammar. In my field of work, some English words are re-appropriated to mean something entirely different to their dictionary definitions.

Even if some related concepts can be non-countable - such as 'noise' and 'sound' - these are not the same as a 'signal'. Signals may be sent *via* mediums that are abstract, but that doesn't make them non-countable. It could be likened to the difference between 'a letter' and 'mail'. 'Mail' is non-countable and can refer to a single piece of correspondence, many pieces, all pieces, or the concept of sending correspondence. 'Letter' is always countable, even though you send letters through the mail.

As for which goes first... if 'sift' is actually the correct term for separating a signal from noise, then it doesn't really matter which goes first. Sifting is used to *separate* things. But it seems reasonable to keep 'signal' in first place as that is thing you want to keep. But it doesn't sound idiomatic to me.

I have some experience in audio production and the term I would use is *filter*. When you filter something, you *remove it*. So I would say I was filtering the thing I want to remove from the thing I want to keep, for example:

> Filter out the noise from the signal.

Comment: So we can never write "signal" in this expression with no article before it? How about "noise"? My guess is that it's not countable, so what should be done with its article?

Comment: Take this sentence from an article in an English newspaper. It is not using "the" before the two nouns. And it is using the expression with "sift", so I guess it is idiomatic as opposed to what you say? *Its artificial intelligence software purports to **sift signal from noise** to figure out which early trends are destined for mass adoption.* https://www.ft.com/content/abc231ac-c288-11e9-a8e9-296ca66511c9

Comment: Here is another newspaper example. *Part of America's failure was an improper ability to **sift signal from noise** and to disseminate this information bureaucratically.* https://asiatimes.com/2022/12/pearl-harbor-redux-us-risks-repeating-strategic-errors/

Comment: @lorentz okay that's some context you didn't previously provide. 'Noise' is sometimes used metaphorically to refer to unimportant information. Like on social media, there might some really important human opinions in amongst the 'noise' of endless memes and chatter from bots. But having seen this before, I've never seen the information you want to keep described as 'signal'. If this is the context, it's a very messy metaphor.

Comment: Journalists and writers makes changes to clichés all the time. That is all this is. If you said this: **They want to sift the signal from the noise on this channel, then, yes, you need a the**.

Comment: @Astralbee This jargon is ubiquitous in STEM: signals are not necessarily messages to be transmitted, but rather effects one may or may not observe. In this sense, signals = information. More specifically, information that is interesting enough for us to **actively** try to obtain it. Looking for an image of a specific object in a vast array of images might be described as a signal/noise situation, even if it is far removed from electromagnetic impulses. And with big data/ML gaining increased mainstream adoption, the "very messy metaphor" might become the norm one day, who knows :)

Comment: Survey finds asset managers embrace growing stream of data but struggle to **sift signal from noise** https://www.marketwatch.com/story/survey-finds-asset-managers-embrace-growing-stream-of-data-but-struggle-to-sift-signal-from-noise-11627413318

Comment: Why did we build this?
It is increasingly challenging for security teams to **sift signal from noise** due to the overwhelming amount of security data generated by cloud infrastructure. https://panther.com/blog/greynoise-threat-intelligence-in-panther/ Among many other hits.

Answer (score 0):

sift signal from noise is fine.

Please refer to the man who wrote the most important book on communication theory.

[A Mathematical Theory of Communication by Shannon and Weaver](https://monoskop.org/images/b/be/Shannon_Claude_E_Weaver_Warren_The_Mathematical_Theory_of_Communication_1963.pdf)

- **All of these changes in the transmitted signal are called noise.**

**signal and noise are concepts** and do not require any determiner in phrases like **sift signal from noise.** Please see page 7 of the article: Message, channel, sender, receiver are all concepts in the theory.

Anyone interested in communication and translation should read this paper. Of course, there are times when one will use the signal, a signal or signals.

> Why did we build this? It is increasingly challenging for security
> teams to **sift signal from noise** due to the overwhelming amount of
> security data generated by cloud infrastructure.

[sift signal from noise](https://panther.com/blog/greynoise-threat-intelligence-in-panther/)

The Financial Times
Those are predictions from Black Swan, a London-based start-up that hoovers up data from social media, online forums, product review websites as well as other sources and then analyses it to divine what consumers want. Its artificial intelligence software purports to **sift signal from noise** to figure out which early trends are destined for mass adoption.
[Financial Times](https://www.ft.com/content/abc231ac-c288-11e9-a8e9-296ca66511c9)

Comment: Your quote has an article!! "All of these changes in ***the*** transmitted signal are called noise".

Comment: A signal is a concept and doesn't require a determiner??? Do you mean a signal is *abstract*? It may not be tangible in the case of radio communication, but a signal is something deliberately created, sent, received, and is measurable. There are many other abstracts in communication such as *sound*, but signals are not one of them.

Comment: @Astralbee Yes, true. But sift signal from noise is still correct. Notice what I said: in phrases like sift signal from noise, you don't need a determiner. Yes, a signal here is abstract. It is also a concept, an abstract concept. I was trying to show that it is a concept. I think the NYT journalist knows the word filter. It was not used on purpose, because it is a cliché. To filter out noise would be the same thing here. To separate wheat from chaff, you have to do blah, blah blah.

Comment: Ah thank you whoever removed that minus point. :)

Answer (score -1):

I. Here's how *sift* works:

> Sift the flour before mixing in the butter.

*Sift X* - X has to be your "haystack" normally, but if you want to talk about the "needle" you are looking for as well, the expression is *sift {needle} from {haystack}" (reference: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sift+from) or "sift {needle} out of {haystack}"

So you would *sift signal from noise*, *sift signal out of noise*, but the thing you are actually *sifting* is the noise.

II. Here's how articles work:

> What is the correct expression in English? Is it with "the" or without it?

When you say *sift signal from noise*, do you subjectively believe that the reader/listener should know *which signal* you mean?  This may be true if you were talking about a signal earlier in conversation, or there is another reason.  If so, use *the.*

If the reader/listener doesn't need to know or care which signal, then use *a/an.*

If "which signal?" is a question that doesn't make sense at all, because you are not talking about an actual signal, then don't use an article at all.